# SpriteKit - Can't understand what size to make background

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am completely confused on how to correctly size my lans background image which is landscape based. As of right now I'm doing `GameScene(size: self.frame.size)` and I print out the size of the screen so I know what size to make my background and it turns out my background should be 1024x768 but that doesn't seem like landscape dimensions? So I made my background 1024x768 but the entire image doesn't fit into my iphone when its landscape because the iphone lanscape dimensions arent 1024x768. How do I make a background that will look 1:1 with the dimensions of my iphone? The only way I can think is if I set the `GameScene(size: CGPoint(x: 1334, y: 750))`  but then wont it be screwed up for any other device? What's the best way to approach this? I have an artist who is going to make a background for me but I have no idea what dimensions to give him.

Comment: Set the scale mode of and the size of your scene correctly in the view controller before it's presented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When dealing with scenes for Sprite Kit, try not to focus on the screen size, because screen size is no longer a factor (now this is not 100% absolute fact, this is a general rule to go by)

Instead,  treat your SKScene as if it was a virtual screen.  The size of your SKScene is the "resolution" of your SKScene, and the OS will work in the background to figure out how to convert 1 virtual pixel (From here on out we will call point) to screen pixels( referred to here on out as pixels)

Now there is only 1 special case where the OS will change the resolution (scene size) to match the screen, and that is `.resizeFill`  The other 3 will never change resolution on you.

`.aspectFill` and `.aspectFit` will ensure that your point to pixel conversion keeps and equal width and height (e.g. 1 point could equal 4x4 pixels)  The only difference is `.aspectFill` will expand to fill the entire screen, meaning that excess points will be rendered outside the native screen bounds [ so (0,0) may lie 20 pixels left of the left most pixel, thus not being visible] and .aspectFit will fill till it hits a screen border, leaving black bars to fill the unused pixels.

Now `.fill` does not keep and equal width and height point to pixel ratio, and in the case of a 4:3 going to a 16:9 screen,  you will notice that your point to pixel will be 5:4 because a 16:9 screen is 25% wider than a 4:3.  This gets you the fatty effect.

So when dealing with your game you need to figure out the desired effect.  If you set your scene size to 1024x768, then all non retina iPads will have a 1:1 pixel to point ratio, where retina has 2:1 pixels to point ratio.  For an iphone 5, you would get roughly 1.14 pixels to every point (iphone is 1168 and your scene is 1024, so you do 1168/1024) then of the 768, you would be loosing 25%, because the ipad is 25% taller than an iphone in landscape.  This means only 576 points will be showing, and the rest are in invisible screen space.

Basically, you can never get a 1:1 with both an iPad and an iPhone doing a universal app because you are working with 2 different aspect ratios.  You are going to have to make 2 different sets of assets, or take some creative liberties that doesn't alter the gaming experience.  This depends entirely on the game and unfortunately nobody will be able to answer it till they have an understanding of your game.